# Java. Сравнение массивов

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, подскажите как можно сравнить 2 массива? Есть код, в нем 2 одинаковых массива, но условие не проходит.

```
package VarA;

public class Task4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] password = {"q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"};

        if(args.equals(password))
            System.out.println("Пароль верный");
        else {
            System.out.println("Пароль неверный");
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            System.out.print(args[i]);

        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i < password.length; i++)
            System.out.print(password[i]);              
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`array1.equals(array2)` тоже самое, что и `array1 == array2`, сравниваются адреса, а не содержимое.

Вам нужно использовать [Arrays.equals(array1, array2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])) для сравнения, т.е.

```
if(Arrays.equals(args, password)) {...
```